# Images should only load when scrolling down to reduce bandwidth

Tags: php, css, ajax, image, directory

well, i am reading out an image folder with lets say 300 images with php.
It runs fine.

To reduce bandwidth, i want to load the images only, if they are in the viewport.

Comment: What do you mean with "site end" ?

Comment: whoops sorry, with "site end" i mean if i would scroll, then the images should be loading, otherwise it shouldnt. Sorry, my english isnt the best. Hope you are understanding what i mean. Pagination is no option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you want your images to load when you scroll down the page. So, you need to use [lazy loading](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) in your application.

[See this example](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/index.php?c=basic)

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Nouman, may i bother you? ^^ So, i am using lazy loading now, but it is not working as it should. Only the pictures are loading, which are in the viewport. If i scroll, i can see nothing. If i lookup the sourcecode, i can see that every image i can't see, still having the src:data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==" as its placeholder. If i scroll, lets say to 50% down and i reload the page, i can see the images, which were in the 50% scrolled viewport. Any idea?

Comment: okay, solved. My jquery plugin was just out of date. Sorry! I used a hostedlibrary and while its working with lightbox it didnt work with lazyload. (it was above 1.3.1, thats why i didnt change it) Anyway, i updated it and it runs as it should. Many thanks for your hint with lazyloading.

Answer (score 0):

So you are looking for an infinite scrolling, as far as I understand.

You have some plugins that may help you:

http://jscroll.com/

http://infinite-scroll.com